# apache2 proxy error - are we beeing attacked / hijacked?

Tags: apache-2.4, proxy, ddos, attacks

We are getting a lot of load since 2 days on our webserver (apache2.4, wordpress + woocommerce, nodeJS server)

Now I saw a lot of URLs in the error logs which I dont know. Most of them from china. It looks like we are beeing attacked / hijacked.

We already set up cloudflare today, but that did not help.

Is it possible that our webserver is compromised?

```
    [Sun Dec 17 19:16:56.518298 2017] [proxy:warn] [pid 28468] [client 119.23.132.94:54654] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL kyfw.12306.cn:443. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Sun Dec 17 19:16:56.754870 2017] [proxy_http:error] [pid 28458] (20014)Internal error (specific information not available): [client 89.35.52.133:63271] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server en.027steel.com:80, referer: http://en.027steel.com/messages_list.html
[Sun Dec 17 19:16:56.755036 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 28458] [client 89.35.52.133:63271] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by http://en.027steel.com/messages_list.html, referer: http://en.027steel.com/messages_list.html
[Sun Dec 17 19:16:56.757022 2017] [proxy:warn] [pid 28554] [client 49.79.224.12:63799] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL gslb.miaopai.com:443. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Sun Dec 17 19:16:56.928145 2017] [proxy:warn] [pid 28533] [client 120.24.184.163:58018] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL kyfw.12306.cn:443. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Sun Dec 17 19:16:56.960927 2017] [proxy:warn] [pid 28554] [client 112.74.200.139:25871] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL 121.9.223.53:8084. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Sun Dec 17 19:16:56.989820 2017] [proxy:warn] [pid 28529] [client 119.23.132.94:51602] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL kyfw.12306.cn:443. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Sun Dec 17 19:16:57.016958 2017] [proxy:warn] [pid 28545] [client 120.77.59.113:57570] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL kyfw.12306.cn:443. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Sun Dec 17 19:16:57.055387 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 28562] [client 212.7.220.19:47966] AH00898: DNS lookup failure for: www.timberland-outlet.us.org returned by http://www.timberland-outlet.us.org/, referer: http://www.us.org
[Sun Dec 17 19:16:57.155617 2017] [proxy:warn] [pid 28549] [client 188.190.33.30:57847] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL static.doubleclick.net:443. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Sun Dec 17 19:16:57.270051 2017] [proxy:warn] [pid 28485] [client 119.23.151.217:49512] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL kyfw.12306.cn:443. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Sun Dec 17 19:16:57.484263 2017] [proxy:warn] [pid 28485] [client 144.255.150.191:50266] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL lgn.yy.com:443. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Sun Dec 17 19:16:57.484438 2017] [proxy:warn] [pid 28485] [client 122.114.240.237:61281] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL livecmt-1.bilibili.com:2243. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Sun Dec 17 19:16:57.671504 2017] [proxy:warn] [pid 28485] [client 123.129.217.12:65502] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL lgn.yy.com:443. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Sun Dec 17 19:16:58.246495 2017] [proxy:warn] [pid 28485] [client 47.93.38.251:18652] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL kyfw.12306.cn:443. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Sun Dec 17 19:16:58.546077 2017] [proxy:warn] [pid 28455] [client 119.39.174.124:11956] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL m.flycua.com:443. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Sun Dec 17 19:16:58.629628 2017] [proxy:warn] [pid 28481] [client 221.194.44.242:38339] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL lgn.yy.com:443. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Sun Dec 17 19:16:58.741615 2017] [proxy:warn] [pid 28565] [client 139.211.192.12:57312] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL guestapi.ihg.com:443. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Sun Dec 17 19:16:58.783764 2017] [proxy:warn] [pid 28511] [client 168.1.195.212:1802] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL m.facebook.com:443. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Sun Dec 17 19:16:58.977043 2017] [proxy:warn] [pid 28540] [client 173.208.246.26:63285] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL www.google.co.uk:443. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Sun Dec 17 19:16:59.079705 2017] [proxy:warn] [pid 28532] [client 119.29.169.74:3535] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL 114.236.143.110:8091. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Sun Dec 17 19:16:59.252594 2017] [proxy:warn] [pid 28443] [client 120.24.184.163:41568] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL kyfw.12306.cn:443. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Sun Dec 17 19:16:59.816122 2017] [proxy:warn] [pid 28466] [client 58.221.58.108:32196] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL lgn.yy.com:443. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Sun Dec 17 19:17:00.041293 2017] [proxy:warn] [pid 28466] [client 119.23.132.94:40324] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL kyfw.12306.cn:443. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Sun Dec 17 19:17:00.163881 2017] [proxy:warn] [pid 28569] [client 119.23.151.217:54842] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL kyfw.12306.cn:443. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Sun Dec 17 19:17:00.292064 2017] [proxy:warn] [pid 28489] [client 119.23.132.94:46098] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL kyfw.12306.cn:443. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Sun Dec 17 19:17:00.301479 2017] [proxy:warn] [pid 28527] [client 123.129.217.12:9064] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL lgn.yy.com:443. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Sun Dec 17 19:17:00.395634 2017] [proxy:warn] [pid 28519] [client 123.129.217.182:17761] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL lgn.yy.com:443. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Sun Dec 17 19:17:00.396112 2017] [proxy:warn] [pid 28519] [client 47.52.221.163:56439] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL booking.airasia.com:443. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Sun Dec 17 19:17:00.549797 2017] [proxy:warn] [pid 28430] [client 120.24.184.163:35502] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL kyfw.12306.cn:443. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Sun Dec 17 19:17:00.675536 2017] [proxy:warn] [pid 28519] [client 117.87.220.93:55935] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL appblog.sina.com.cn:443. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Sun Dec 17 19:17:00.743393 2017] [proxy:warn] [pid 28496] [client 120.24.184.163:48210] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL kyfw.12306.cn:443. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Sun Dec 17 19:17:00.858752 2017] [proxy:warn] [pid 28533] [client 117.48.215.28:59581] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL m.10010.com:443. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Sun Dec 17 19:17:00.915752 2017] [proxy:warn] [pid 28497] [client 120.78.15.46:37622] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL kyfw.12306.cn:443. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
```

Our vhost config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName app.test.laflor.ch
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/la-flor-frontend
  Options -Indexes

  ProxyRequests on
  ProxyPass /api/ http://wordpress.local/wp-json/frontend/
  ProxyPassReverse /api/ http://wordpress.local/wp-json/frontend/
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:61010/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:61010/

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress
  ServerName wordpress.local
  Options -Indexes

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName wordpress.test.laflor.ch
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress
  Options -Indexes
 <Directory "/var/www/html/wordpress">
         RewriteEngine On
         RewriteBase /
         RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
         RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Also, the VM has 2GB of ram and apache is using all RAM after ~15minutes. I think this is related to the attack.

What can we do to stop this madness? Re-install the server? Get a new IP address / move to another hoster?

Comment: It looks like `mod_proxy` isn't installed correctly, which will be in the main apache configuration. The traffic is probably just port scanners but it's causing issues with your VM. It may be that you have inherited an IP address that has been attacked by a botnet previously.

Comment: Do you recognize those hosts as yours? Have you set `ProxyRequests off` or is it set to on somewhere in your config? If you don't want your server used as a forward proxy set it to off inmediatly.

Comment: It was indeed a compromised IP. We switched IPs and now its fine.